# Google Maps API Many markers link

Tags: xml, api, hyperlink, maps

I have a lot of markers. Markers come from XML file. I need have a link on markers. Ex.

Marker 1 - http://example.com/id-1

Marker 2 - http://example.com/id-2

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="util.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.216204,19.124706);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 11,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapka"), myOptions);

    downloadUrl("data.xml", function(data) {
      var markers = data.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
      for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
        var id = markers[i].getAttribute("mid");

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: latlng, map: map, url: id});

       google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() { window.location.href = id; });
       }
     });
  }
</script>
```

this don't work. Please help.